# backcounting timer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want a timer wich is starting if a button is pressed.
while the timer is running, it is not possible to press the button again. and a alert will show up..
have you an idea how to realize it?
Tank you!

Comment: You need do some of your own research first. Stackoverflow is not the place to get people to your own work for you. You should also attempt to ensure that your post has the correct grammar (such as correct capitals, spellings and articles).

Comment: sorry i´m from germany and this was my first post. i`m new here.. the next time i will make it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) the first time the button is pressed, and while the timer is valid, don't allow the action to happen, and popup your alert.

Store your NSTimer in a property on your object.

Interface:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

Implementation:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    if(self.timer == nil || ![self.timer isValid]) {
        // Allow the action (set the timer interval to what suits your needs)
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 invocation:nil repeats:NO];

        // DO THE ACTION HERE!
        NSLog(@"You can do it this time!");
    } else {
        // Deny the action (perhaps popup an alert)
        NSLog(@"Can't do that yet!");
    }
}
```

Comment: it work realy great thank you so much for the fast answer!!!!